# Angular2 boot.ts Unexpected error

Tags: javascript, angular, directory

I am currently trying out different folder structures for Angular 2 and when trying to start a local server I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/prod/app/TypeScript/boot
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/prod/app/TypeScript/boot
```

Folder structure:

index.html

dev

---app

------TypeScript

-----------app.component.ts

-----------boot.ts

Comment: We obviously need to see your code(We are not majicans).... Plunker would be awesome!

Comment: Here is the plunker url, sorry if I have set it up wrong never used it before.

https://plnkr.co/edit/GiIxMgR8VuABKkVEMRwH?p=catalogue

Comment: There are no problems... Only problem i can see happening is that you the browser didnt get the files.. Can you check on your console if there is any 404 or like CANT GET, or something similar?

Comment: There are no 404 errors in the console or network tab.

Comment: Then i dont understand your problem... Maybe [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) can serve you as a guide..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to configure SystemJS like this:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      app: 'prod/app'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/TypeScript/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

In your case, the `defaultExtension` property doesn't apply so the URL corresponding to your module isn't correct: `http://localhost:3000/prod/app/TypeScript/boot` instead of `http://localhost:3000/prod/app/TypeScript/boot.js`.

Moreover it's perhaps a typo but you have a `dev` folder and not a `prod` one...

Comment: I currently have a gulp file that complies the typescript into the prod folder but with exactly the same folder structure. The map property has fixed my issue thanks for the help :).